# Adding aditional versions of php in MAMP

Tags: virtualization, mamp

On my production server the highest version of php i can run is 5.3.13.

Looking at the preferences panel in MAMP(v2.1.3) i have two options for the php either 5.2.17 or 5.4.10.

Is there an install or a plugin that i can add to allow me to use additional releases of php, so that i can mimic the environment i have setup on the production server ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you'll probably need MAMP *Pro* to have PHP 5.3.x available:

> - PHP 5.2.17
> - PHP 5.3.14 (MAMP PRO only)
> - PHP 5.4.4

Source: http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html